# Query in firebase dataSnapshot returning null

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to save data, and I have some problem in returning the data via key from Firebase 
So in short, this is my firebase page:

[this is my firebase page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIZzw.png) 
first I did without using Query and it did work but with Query, it's a bit more flexible so I try doing that way and it did not work 
so here is my code and I hope you would be able to help me

```
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Objects");

            Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("Users").child(key//key is a string value entered by the user ).orderByChild("name").equalTo(name//the name the user is searching for );

            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot!=null) {
                        for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (datasnapshot!=null) {
                                textView.setText(dataSnapshot.child(key).getValue(Artest.class).getName());
                                editText.setText("");
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(SearchByKey.this, "in the for loop there was null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            textView2.setText("null....");
                            }

                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(SearchByKey.this, "dataSnapshot was null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textView2.setText("null");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }`
```

this code works but it doesn't involve using Query

```
String keyy= editText.getText().toString();                        
firebaseDatabase.child("users").child(keyy).addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
   if (dataSnapshot == null ) {                               
    Toast.makeText(SearchByKey.this, "dataSnapshot was null", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      }    
     if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(keyy)){                            
     textView.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(Artest.class).getName());                                
     textView2.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(Artest.class).getGoal());                                
     editText.setText("");                            }
     else {
     Toast.makeText(SearchByKey.this, "make sure you entered the right 
     key , try again ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                
     editText.setText("");                            }                 
       }
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
     {
     }
```

hey again this is how I manage to solve this issue 
first , I make the search depandes only on the key , 
I took snapshot on the full users ... 
in short , this is the code gives me a perfect output :

`firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Objects");`

```
final String keyy= editTextart.getText().toString();
            Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("users");
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(Search.this, "dataSnapshot was null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        textView.setText(dataSnapshot.child(keyy).getValue(Artest.class).getName());
                        textView2.setText(dataSnapshot.child(keyy).getValue(Artest.class).getGoal());
                        editTextart.setText("");
                    }
                }
```

hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Please add the declaration of `firebaseDatabase`

Comment: Done, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Small typo -

change `Users` to `users` :-)

Comment: thanks for your reply but I did that and it's still not working,

Comment: I can see you looped the children of `dataSnapShot` then again you are getting child with key that does not even exist. What exactly you want to do.?

Comment: hey friend , I want to retrieve the value which the user search for so if the user search for example "SALMAN" I want to return to him SALMAN and the Goal is: The Pase Programmer ever

Comment: Do one thing, Get all users using `Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("users")` as `dataSnapShot`. build the list using for loop and filter the list according to your needs.

Comment: great idea loved it, try to do it no action happened can I show you the code?

Comment: There you go. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your using an incorrect child. Please change this line:

```
Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("Users")...
```

with

```
Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("users")...
```

Use `u` lowercase.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I did that and it's still not working,

Comment: Use just `Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("users").child("7").child("name");` and see if it works. To get only one name.

Comment: hey friend I did like this `                Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("users").child("7").child("name");
` and `                                    textView.setText(dataSnapshot.child("7").getValue(Artest.class).getName());
` but still it did not work .

Comment: In this case, you only need to use: `Query query = firebaseDatabase.child("users").child("7"); ` and `textView.setText(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.cla‌​ss));` Does it work?

Comment: I did not work, I found another solution that works but without using Query, I am going to post it, now

Answer (score 0):

For the particular query you have above (where you're just calling `child(key)` you should just have to do something like following (not call `getChildren()`)

```
Artest artist = dataSnapshot.getValue(Artest.class);
```

Comment: hey, friend, I did what you have said but the apps crash,

Comment: what crash are you getting?